# Does accordion cause redraw of entire page?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, accordion, repaint

I'm reviewing design for mobile website with accordion on top and many elements below, when accordion opens all elements get pushed down.
I am wondering if the act of opening the accordion will force the mobile browser to redraw the entire page and slow it down.
Is this correct? is there a better way to look at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if the act of opening the accordion will force the
>   mobile browser to redraw the entire page and slow it down. Is this
>   correct?

It's hard to say: the answer depends on:

1. the browser you are using and the rendering algorithm it implements
2. the actual structure of your page

But yes, according to the following resources, opening the accordion at the top of the page will most likely cause a **reflow**(*) that will involve the rest of the page.

(*) take a look at the articles for explanations on what **repaint** and **reflow** mean

Alexander Skutin, [What Every Frontend Developer Should Know About Webpage Rendering](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/webpage-rendering-101/) (2014, May 26)

> Browsers are doing their best to restrict repaint/reflow to the area
>   that covers the changed elements only. For example, a size change in
>   an absolute/fixed positioned element only affects the element itself
>   and its descendants, whereas a similar change in a statically
>   positioned element triggers reflow for **all the subsequent elements**.

(bold is mine)

So according to this, placing the accordion on top of the page would affect also **all the subsequent elements**.

This other older article seems to reinforce the same hypothesis:

Nicole Sullivan, [Reflows & Repaints: CSS Performance making your JavaScript slow?](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) (2009, March 27)

> Reflow of an element causes the subsequent reflow of all child and
>   ancestor elements **as well as any elements following it in the DOM**.

(bold is mine)

---

> is there a better way to look at this?

I understand that you may want to steer your design from the beginning in the right direction but I would suggest you not to be concerned about this prematurely.

You may want to quickly realize a prototype to make sure performances are acceptable on the devices you will want to support and as a last resource you could still disable animations based on the user agent for devices that does not support them properly.

You may want your developers to take a look at this other article that has some solid guidelines to limit browser reflows:

Lindsey Simon, [Minimizing browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)

> 1. Reduce unnecessary DOM depth. Changes at one level in the DOM tree can cause changes at every level of the tree - all the way up to the
>      root, and all the the way down into the children of the modified node.
>      This leads to more time being spent performing reflow.
> 2. Minimize CSS rules, and remove unused CSS rules.
> 3. If you make complex rendering changes such as animations, do so out of the flow. Use position-absolute or position-fixed to accomplish
>      this.
> 4. Avoid unnecessary complex CSS selectors - descendant selectors in particular - which require more CPU power to do selector matching.